# MATLAB: Test if anonymous vector is a subset of R^n

Tags: matlab, math, vector

I'm trying to use MatLab code as a way to learn math as a programmer.

So reading I'm this [post](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/Subspaces-of-Rn.topicArticleId-20807,articleId-20786.html) about subspaces and trying to build some simple matlab functions that do it for me.

Here is how far I got:

```
function performSubspaceTest(subset, numArgs)
% Just a quick and dirty function to perform subspace test on a vector(subset)
%
% INPUT
% subset        is the anonymous function that defines the vector
% numArgs       is the the number of argument that subset takes

% Author:   Lasse Nørfeldt (Norfeldt)
% Date:     2012-05-30
% License:  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

if numArgs == 1
    subspaceTest = @(subset) single(rref(subset(rand)+subset(rand))) ...
        == single(rref(rand*subset(rand)));

elseif numArgs == 2
    subspaceTest = @(subset) single(rref(subset(rand,rand)+subset(rand,rand))) ...
        == single(rref(rand*subset(rand,rand)));
end
% rand just gives a random number. Converting to single avoids round off
% errors.
% Know that the code can crash if numArgs isn't given or bigger than 2.

outcome = subspaceTest(subset);
if outcome == true
    display(['subset IS a subspace of R^' num2str(size(outcome,2))])
else
    display(['subset is NOT a subspace of R^' num2str(size(outcome,2))])
end
```

And these are the subset that I'm testing

```
%% Checking for subspaces
V = @(x) [x, 3*x]
performSubspaceTest(V, 1)

A = @(x) [x, 3*x+1]
performSubspaceTest(A, 1)

B = @(x) [x, x^2, x^3]
performSubspaceTest(B, 1)

C = @(x1, x3) [x1, 0, x3, -5*x1]
performSubspaceTest(C, 2)
```

running the code gives me this

```
V = 
@(x)[x,3*x]
subset IS a subspace of R^2

A = 
@(x)[x,3*x+1]
subset is NOT a subspace of R^2

B = 
@(x)[x,x^2,x^3]
subset is NOT a subspace of R^3

C = 
@(x1,x3)[x1,0,x3,-5*x1]
subset is NOT a subspace of R^4
```

The C is not working (only works if it only accepts one arg). 
I know that my solution for numArgs is not optimal - but it was what I could come up with at the current moment..

Are there any way to optimize this code so C will work properly and perhaps avoid the ***elseif*** statments for more than 2 args..?

PS: I couldn't seem to find a build-in matlab function that does the hole thing for me..

Comment: I see one problem, as in your test you just check once with rand values. It's in the nature of rands that they can be unlucky chosen for your test.

Comment: For the failing test C you just check if it's a _one_ dimensional subspace. It fails because the subspace is _two_ dimensional.

Comment: @bdecaf so how do I test it for two dimensions?

Comment: Obviously you need two rows. It would look like `subspaceTest = @(subset) single(rref([subset(rand,rand)+subset(rand,rand);subset(rand,rand)+subset(rand,rand)])) ...
    == single(rref([rand*subset(rand,rand);rand*subset(rand,rand)]))` in your notation (just added a second row to each subspace).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. It tests if a given function represents a linear subspace or not. Technically it is only a probabilistic test, but the chance of it failing is vanishingly small.

First, we define a nice abstraction. This higher order function takes a function as its first argument, and applies the function to every row of the matrix `x`. This allows us to test many arguments to `func` at the same time.

```
function y = apply(func,x)
  for k = 1:size(x,1)
    y(k,:) = func(x(k,:));
  end
```

Now we write the core function. Here `func` is a function of one argument (presumed to be a vector in `R^m`) which returns a vector in `R^n`. We apply `func` to 100 randomly selected vectors in `R^m` to get an output matrix. If `func` represents a linear subspace, then the [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) of the output will be less than or equal to `m`.

```
function result = isSubspace(func,m)
  inputs  = rand(100,m);
  outputs = apply(func,inputs);
  result  = rank(outputs) <= m;
```

Here it is in action. Note that the functions take only a single argument - where you wrote `c(x1,x2)=[x1,0,x2]` I write `c(x) = [x(1),0,x(2)]`, which is slightly more verbose, but has the advantage that we don't have to mess around with if statements to decide how many arguments our function has - and this works for functions that take input in `R^m` for any `m`, not just 1 or 2.

```
>> v = @(x) [x,3*x]
>> isSubspace(v,1)
ans =
     1

>> a = @(x) [x(1),3*x(1)+1]
>> isSubspace(a,1)
ans =
     0

>> c = @(x) [x(1),0,x(2),-5*x(1)]
>> isSubspace(c,2)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: interesting. This seems to work most of the time, but you're not answering OP's original question: specifically you are trying to see if the rank of the output it equal to the number of input, which has nothing to do with verifying if a subset is closed

Comment: Do you have a case that it doesn't work on? I expect it will give false positives on examples that are "nearly a subspace" (e.g. they add epsilon to one of the components) but that's a limitation of using floating point to approximate real numbers. I think my answer is good because (a) it's simple (b) it's general and (c) it ties the mathematics neatly into the code.

Comment: aha! @(x)[x^2,3*x^2] should fail as -1 *c(1) = [-1,-3], which doesn't have a corresponding point in R (you would need c(i)). But the rank remains 1. Nice effort though, however theory wins again

Answer (score 1):

The solution of not being optimal barely scratches the surface of the problem.

I think you're doing too much at once: `rref` should not be used and is complicating everything. especially for `numArgs` greater then 1.

Think it through: `[1 0 3 -5]` and `[3 0 3 -5]` are both members of C, but their sum `[4 0 6 -10]` (which belongs in C) is not linear product of the multiplication of one of the previous vectors (e.g. `[2 0 6 -10]` ). So all the `rref` in the world can't fix your problem.

So what can you do instead?

you need to check if

```
(randn*subset(randn,randn)+randn*subset(randn,randn)))
```

is a member of C, which, unless I'm mistaken is a difficult problem: Conceptually you need to iterate through every element of the vector and make sure it matches the predetermined condition. Alternatively, you can try to find a set such that C(x1,x2) gives you the right answer. In this case, you can use [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fminsearch.html) to solve this problem numerically and verify the returned value is within a defined tolerance:

```
[s,error] = fminsearch(@(x) norm(C(x(1),x(2)) - [2 0 6 -10]),[1 1])
s =
   1.999996976386119   6.000035034493023
error =
     3.827680714104862e-05
```

Edit: you need to make sure you can use negative numbers in your multiplication, so don't use rand, but use something else. I changed it to randn.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm note sure I understand how to read it properly. Does fminsearch fill in the x(1) and x(2) by itself until it finds x1 and x2 values that gives a vector which by substraction with another vector of C gives a unit vector..?   I might be a little confused..

Comment: fminsearch finds the closest set of points which minimizes an error. In this case it tries to find a point such that C(x) is as close to `[2 0 6 -10]` as possible. In this case the error is small, but in another case, the error can be big, which would mean your input function is not a subspace.

Comment: Can it be generalized so the input function (in this case C) gets the number of args it accept. something like   
    
     ***[s,error] = fminsearch(@(func, varargs) norm(func(varargs) - [2 0 6 -10]),[1 1])***

It is similar to create a subset of C without declaring each arg. So instead of C(rand,rand) it could have been C(varargs('random')) if should a function should exist... - hope it makes sense..???

Comment: Just looking @ my comment at can see that @(func, varargs) does not make sense.. Just see it as @(varargs) and still have the func(varargs) inside the norm.

Comment: @Norfeldt note that my answer isn't a code solution to what you are looking for, rather, it suggests what you can do. You'll need to run something like this several times and hope to cover many possible solutions before feeling confident you have the right answer. Chris suggests doing a rank calculation of ***100*** different vectors, and while his number may be large it is the cost you pay when doing things numerically